# How to use Azure API Managment to do loadbance?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Can Azure API Management be used to implement load balancing? I want to automatically distribute client calls to a certain API in API Management to multiple different web API services in the background. How can this be achieved without introducing an API gateway?
Thanks!

Comment: API Management doesn't perform any load balancing, so it should be used in conjunction with a load balancer such as Application Gateway or a reverse proxy. For information about using API Management with Application Gateway, see [Integrate API Management in an internal VNet with Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible. From the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/design/gateway).

> API Management doesn't perform any load balancing, so it should be used in conjunction with a load balancer such as Application Gateway or a reverse proxy. For information about using API Management with Application Gateway, see [Integrate API Management in an internal VNet with Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway).

Having said that if you want to use `APIM` merely as LB you are overpaying or maybe your system needs some redesign. APIM is primarily used to proxy the backend APIs wrt., authentication, caching, add rate-limiting, etc., features.